# How to get current IndexSet in a List SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need a little help. I have a List, and currently, to delete an item from the list, I am swipping left, but instead of doing this, I want to click on a " - " button and have the same beheviour.

This is the func that was used to "swipe left" to delete an item " :

```
private func deleteItem(offSets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offSets.map { coreDataViewModel.savedMenu[$0] }.forEach(coreDataViewModel.manager.context.delete)
            coreDataViewModel.saveContext()
        }
    }
```

This is the list :

```
List {
    ForEach(coreDataViewModel.savedCartToShow) { car in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Image("food")
                    .padding()
                Text(car.name ?? "")
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    deleteItem(offSets: <#IndexSet#>)
                } label: {
                    Image("removeCircle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                }
                Text("x\(coreDataViewModel.countDictionary[car.id] ?? 0)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        
    }
```

How can i find what's the line Index Set ?

```
 deleteItem(offSets: <#IndexSet#>)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI, Core Data - Delete List Item with Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687088/swiftui-core-data-delete-list-item-with-context-menu) -- instead of trying to use the `deleteItem(offSets: IndexSet)` function, just delete `car` directly or create a special function that takes the entity and *not* an indexSet

Comment: It worked, thank you @jnpdx !

Comment: Great -- feel free to upvote the helpful answer